# flutter: how to make a little notification which is like a feedback?

Tags: flutter, events, notifications, feedback

I'm trying to make an app on android which do something on pushing a button. After that, I would like to send a feedback for the user about the event, with a little notification which has animation easeinout with a simple text like this at the bottom of the screen: [notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTbSa.jpg)

Is there any simple way to make that with a built-in widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [snackbar](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/snackbars) provides this kind of notification with a straight forward implementation.

Comment: Actually I found it, it's called Toast Message
Here's a yt tutorial: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2tq4RMcAJw&ab_channel=JohannesMilke